# I want to hide the drop down icon when there is no child data in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to hide the drop down icon when there is no child data and show the drop down icon when there is child data presented (have used rowGroup: true for grouping into parent/child lists) in angular4. Can someone tell me if there is any solution?

My drop down icon should be invisible when there is no data under parent node and it should be visible if there is any child data under parent data.

I have tried visible boolean method still nothing is working.

rowGroup: true,

Comment: Can you provide code that you tried!

Comment: I have used rowgroup: true, 
to group all parent child data. But now I want to make it invisible if there is no data under it and make it visible when there is data.

Comment: Yes understood! But where is that code so *I/anyone* can help. Like `dropdown` and `rowGroup`

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, try something like:

```
[class.disable]="!rowGroup"
```

and in your css:

```
 .disable{
  display: none;
  }
```

Comment: I tried this too. It's not working I am using ag-grid.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the :only-child selector.

```
 .dropdown-menu .caret:only-child{
 display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. First you check whether you have got child data or not, and if you got any you are going to change the variable `childDataPresent` value to `true`.

```
childDataPresent: boolean = false;

rowGroup?: childDataPresent;
```

For more information [link](https://unpkg.com/ag-grid@16.0.0/src/ts/entities/colDef.ts).

Comment: I tried but I can't add *ngIf since I use ag-grid I haven't specified any dropdown icon tag in my html.

Comment: can you provide your code, better if you can put them in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nv3ibt)

Comment: The data is rendered from DB and services so I won't be able to set for different values it is set for the whole table. I tried your code but the whole drop down menu for every row is getting disappeared.